# Changing Background of an app

Tags: java, android

Here is sample code:

```
        WallpaperManager wallpaperManager1 = WallpaperManager
                .getInstance(getApplicationContext()); 

        final Drawable wallpaperDrawable1 = wallpaperManager1.getDrawable();
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(wallpaperDrawable1);

        if (wallpaperDrawable1==null)
        {                       
            Resources res = getResources();
            Drawable drawable1=res.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg1);
            getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable1);

        }
```

I wanted to get the system background in my app, If its not there or if user removes it, then I wanted to set a default image from my app to set as app background. Hope Its all clear....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if current system has wallpaper, you use [`peekDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html#peekDrawable%28%29):

```
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable1 = wallpaperManager1.peekDrawable();
```

Also, you missed `else`:

```
if (wallpaperDrawable1==null)
{                       
    Resources res = getResources();
    Drawable drawable1=res.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg1);
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(drawable1);

}
else
{
    getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(wallpaperDrawable1);
}
```

Comment: hey, Its not working, Problem is that the value is never getting null. I m using 2.3.7. When I remove the background from cell, Its showing black screen. The same is getting fetched in my app also... I tried using peekdrawable also. That is also not working. Is there any other method to get the system backgroud to my app.

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned it my previous comment that peekDrawable is also not working. It will return null pointer if no wallpaper is set. Don't no where is the mistake (may be the way we r comparing it), Any way I also think the above mention answer is correct. But its not working. :(

Comment: I've done a little experiment and there's no way to set desktop wallpaper to none. That is, if you have already changed system wallpaper for only **once**. You'll never find `null` value.

Comment: you can confirm your code using new emulator. test it. then change the background and test it again. You'll see that first time running, you will find peekDrawable() return `null`